# Value present on browser but not available in inspect element

Tags: json, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am scraping elements from a web page & I can see the element being visible (numeric value) on the web page in a grayed out box ,but when tried to inspect the element I cant find it between the  tags. I assumed the URL might be any webservice endpoint & tried to GET from postman but it returned mere HTML code not a JSON response.

In general, we can get values between the tags by finding the element & getting innerText attribute in selenium that too failed as there is no text in between the tags.

I cannot post any URL or responses due to security compliance issues in my org. Please advise any other way I can work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my answer , tried running JS code "document.querySelector('input[name=assets_tot_mfr]').value;" and ran it through python execute_script. Thanks